# Setting up auto dhcp mode for eth0

Tags: pi-3, networking, ethernet

I want to set up auto dhcp mode for `eth0` and for this I am using following settings in `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

But after rebooting I get the following output for `eth0`:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:27:eb:c9:2a:5a  
          inet addr:169.254.128.39  Bcast:169.254.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::66b7:7872:1332:1862/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:4 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:109 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:237 (237.0 B)  TX bytes:16639 (16.2 KiB)
```

My router address is `192.168.1.1`. Thus from where is `eth0` getting its address `169.254.128.39`? What is the correct way for using dhcp mode for `eth0` in raspberry pi 3?

Comment: It works out of the box, if you don't fiddle with it. What OS? What have YOU done?

Comment: The RPi interface has been assigned an IPv4 link local address because no DHCP server could be found...  How are you connecting your RPi to your network?  Are you connecting it directly to the router?

Comment: yes I am directly connection it to router

Comment: Are you running NOOBS or Raspbian? What is the output of:  `sudo systemctl status dhcpcd`

Comment: You have only received 4 packets at that point despite sending out 109 - is the Ethernet cable properly connected at both ends (are the LEDs on on the RPi and the Router)?  It might just be that you haven't allowed quite enough time for the normal DHCP handshaking but what does the system log files say {I don't use `systemd` so I do not know what a user of that (the default these days) can expect}...

Comment: What OS/kernel version are you running?